# Webshim calendar gets weird in "multi page template" Jqm

Tags: jquery-mobile, webshim

Nothing can explain better then fiddle:
www.jsfiddle.net/Dt2TE/15/

Compare with  where their isn't any multie page view.
www.jsfiddle.net/Dt2TE/9/
There is some JS that doesn't get properly loaded into the other page (#two).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery mobile needs to initialized before webshims, otherwise you get exactly this result. As I wrote the jQm compatibility things, I wasn't aware, that jQM can have multiple pages in one document and only enhances one of them.

I needed to change some parts in polyfiller to support this. Here are the changes: https://github.com/aFarkas/webshim/commit/03b425a2258a8c168c165dbde58ec3a09ae76433

A working example can be seen here: 
http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/demos/webforms/jquery-mobile.html

And here an updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/Dt2TE/31/

```
//jQM: set waitReady to false
webshims.setOptions('waitReady', false);        

//jQM: set wsdoc to active page or false
webshims.setOptions('wsdoc', $('.ui-page-active').updatePolyfill().get(0) || false);

//jQM: update polyfills on pageinit and change active page
$(document).on('pageinit', function(e){
    webshims.setOptions('wsdoc', e.target);
    $(e.target).updatePolyfill();
});
```

Comment: Yes jQm can have this called ajax pages. When you load the new page into current document. It can be really hard to get that too work if you have an app with alot of JS/ID. That's why I turned that off :). Anyway this multiple page is kind the same but at least you already have all the data in the document. I'll give it a new try later, I will keep the 'popup' for the moment. Where can I see when the new stable version gets out? I'll see if I can give you a fiddle for that bug!

Comment: New releases can be seen here: https://github.com/aFarkas/webshim/releases or for your feedreader https://github.com/aFarkas/webshim/releases.atom